# How to search only post and page title in wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, search

I want to search according page and post title only. is it possible?
my search code in header file is below

```
<form method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search...', 'consulting' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_search_query() ); ?>" name="s" /></div>
    <button type="submit" style="height:7.5vh;"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: That will depend on the `get_search_query()` function and what it searches on I would imagine

Comment: this is wordpress search, please help me to find only title

Comment: u mean this? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96369/search-post-title-only

Comment: yes like this. @Hash

Comment: And this has what exactly to do with CakePHP?

Answer (score 1):

in search.php use below query to override default search functionality or you can use custom template

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            's' => $keyword,
            'cat' => $catSearchID,
            'tag'   => $tag-slug,
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'location' => $post_location_search ,
        );

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: in wordpress have searchform.php, so where put the code

Comment: before query execution start.